# Set CurrentPrincipal in an asynchronous login in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, asynchronous

I've been searching the web for this, and couldn't really find a solution that actually worked. Situation is as follows: I've got a WPF application, where I want to present the user with a simple logon form. Trying to work MVVM, so I've got a LoginViewModel with the following code behind the login command:

```
try
        {
            WithClient(servfact.GetServiceClient<IAccountService>(), proxy =>
            {
                principal = proxy.AuthenticateUser(Login, password);
            });
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        }
        catch(...) { ... }
```

"WithClient" is a short method in my viewmodel baseclass, which I use to instantiate and dispose of my service proxies:

```
    protected void WithClient<T>(T proxy, Action<T> codeToExecute)
    {
        try { codeToExecute(proxy); }
        finally
        {
            IDisposable toDispose = (proxy as IDisposable);
            if(toDispose != null) { toDispose.Dispose(); }
        }
    }
```

Now, most of my services are Async, and I've got an async variant of WithClient going on, which also works fine:

```
        protected async Task WithClientAsync<T>(T proxy, Func<T, Task> codeToExecute)
    {
        try { await codeToExecute(proxy); }
        finally
        {
            IDisposable toDispose = (proxy as IDisposable);
            if(toDispose != null) { toDispose.Dispose(); }
        }
    }
```

The trouble begins whenever I also want to do the login asynchronously. Obviously I don't want the UI to freeze up as I do the login (or visit any WCF service for that matter). That in itself is working fine, but the problem sits in the piece of code where I set the CurrentPrincipal. This problem is probably familiar to most of you: it seems to set it just fine. Then in my program I want to use the CurrentPrincipal (either on the client side or to send the users login to a WCF service in a messageheader), but it seems to be reset to a standard GenericPrincipal. When I revert the login back to being synchronous, the CurrentPrincipal is just fine. So in short: how do I set the principal in the asynchronous code, having it persist later on, instead of reverting back to a standard principal?

Comment: I can't help but I'm curious what's the difference between your `WithClient` and an [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement?

Comment: Well, if I did the same thing with a using statement, I would need to have my service factory create the necessary service, do the wcf calls I want to do, and then dispose the services again. I would have to do that manually everytime. Now, I just need to wrap the calls I want to make with "withclient" and don't have to worry about closing the proxy. I do the error handling in the code (codeToExecute), and whatever happens there, I'm sure the finally block (where I dispose the proxy) will always be executed.

Comment: But this is exactly what `using` does. If you discompile with JustDecompile you would see that the `using` became a `try` and `finally` block doing the dispose in case the object is not null at that time. The `using` is just [syntactic sugar](http://possiblythemostboringblogever.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/c-syntactic-sugar-using-statement.html).

Comment: Well in that particular case, I believe you just taught me something ;) thank you!

Concerning the actual problem: check out this url, where I posted the same problem, and my own solution to it. http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1003460/Set-CurrentPrincipal-in-an-asynchronous-login-in-W

Comment: Just a quick update concerning the wrapping of WCF calls in a using block: when the proxy ends up in a faulted state, the dispose call throws an exception at you. The right way to do it is to avoid using blocks and test the state of the proxy before disposing it. 
`        protected void WithClient<T>(T proxy, Action<T> codeToExecute)
        {
            try { codeToExecute(proxy); }
            finally
            {
                var client = proxy as ICommunicationObject;
                client.DisposeSafely();
            }
        }`

Comment: With the DisposeSafely extention method looking like this:           ` public static void DisposeSafely(this ICommunicationObject communication)
        {
            if(communication.State == CommunicationState.Faulted) { communication.Abort(); }
            else { communication.Close(); }

            var dispose = communication as IDisposable;
            if(dispose != null) { dispose.Dispose(); }
        }`

Comment: Yes, the `using` statement is just a `try/finally` syntactic sugar operation. Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, well, no answer in a year. No worries, since I managed to solve this myself: I simply wrapped a singleton around it all:

```
    public sealed class CurrentPrincipalFacade : IPrincipal
{
    #region Singleton mechanism

    private static readonly CurrentPrincipalFacade instance = new CurrentPrincipalFacade();
    public static CurrentPrincipalFacade Instance { get { return instance; } }
    private CurrentPrincipalFacade() { }

    #endregion

    #region IPrincipal members

    public IPrincipal Principal { get; set; }

    public IIdentity Identity { get { return Principal == null ? null : Principal.Identity; } }

    public bool IsInRole(string role) { return Principal != null && Principal.IsInRole(role); }

    public void Reset() { Principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(""), new string[] { }); }
    #endregion}
```

So I set that after login. I guess the problem was I was setting the principal in another thread, which got lost when I got out of that?